# How to get OWL file from opencyc?

Tags: java, ontology, owl, protege

I want to get some domain of knowledge in opencyc KB in OWL form.. Assume we want to take fruit. Then how can I take this knowledge as OWL form? Because I want to load that file into protege as OWL ontology. So how can I do this?
I already downloaded OWL files from [opencyc site](http://opencyc.org/downloads) and I tried to load into protege. But I got error as
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.parser.ProtegeOWLParser$1.invokeARP(Unknown Source)
Plz help me...

Answer (score 0):

Those files are compressed with gzip (hence the `.gz` extension). After downloading, you'll need to uncompress them. I'm guessing that you're using Windows: you can either use the gzip utility in cygwin, if you use [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), or download a utility like [7zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/).

Comment: I loaded that file.. but I want to split ontology into several ontologies.do you know any mechanism?